# Docker Error ! Docker daemon is not running

Tags: docker, docker-compose, windows-10

when Trying to run **docker run -d -p 80:80 docker/getting-started** it will show an error
windows 10 pro

docker: error during connect: Post http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.40/containers/create: open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified. In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run elevated to connect. This error may also indicate that the docker daemon is not running.
See 'docker run --help'.

Comment: Try to run your PowerShell with admin privileges

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can try any of the below steps.

1. execute the below command

   `cd "C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker"`

   `./DockerCli.exe -SwitchDaemon`
2. Docker Reset to Factory Defaults

[image]

Comment: [![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gfA9m.png

Comment: [![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gfA9m.png

Comment: after the above Demon run still getting error   D:\Softwares\UI_Kafka>docker pull provectuslabs/kafka-ui
Using default tag: latest
error during connect: This error may indicate that the docker daemon is not running.: Post "http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.24/images/create?fromImage=provectuslabs%2Fkafka-ui&tag=latest": open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: above is not working for me ... can you help me