# Unable to start docker on windows 10

Tags: docker, windows-10

Facing issue after installing Docker on windows 10 Enterprise by following official site https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/

Run Docker:
`C:\WINDOWS\system32>docker run -d -p 80:80 docker/getting-started`

```
ERROR:
docker: error during connect: Post http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.40/containers/create: open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run elevated to connect. This error may also indicate that the docker daemon is not running.
See `docker run --help`

**Information**

Windows Version: windows 10 Enterprise
Docker Desktop Version: 19.03.11

Are you running inside a virtualized Windows e.g. on a cloud server or on a mac VM: no, running natively on windows 10

Comment: Are you certain that Docker is running? You should be able to see the whale icon in your notifications area and hovering above it should say "Docker Desktop is Running"

Comment: Can check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64464030/docker-error-docker-daemon-is-not-running/64464265#64464265

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried updating the windows os and reinstalling docker?  This was an issue I had earlier with win10 version and docker.

Answer (score 0):

Can try any of the below steps.

1. execute the below command In Powershell elevated access

   `cd "C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker"`

   `./DockerCli.exe -SwitchDaemon`
2. Docker Reset to Factory Defaults

[image]